# How to add link to an image

Tags: hyperlink

I am working on a login/register page and i forget that how can i insert a link on a image. Here is my code...

```
<div class="social-media">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="images/facebook.png"></li>
          <li><img src="images/twitter.png"></li>
          <li><img src="images/linkedin.png"></li>
          <li><img src="images/instagram.png"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can i insert a link....

Comment: It's HTML basics. Have you tried something so far? There is no own effort in your posted code.

Comment: `<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>`

Comment: It's correct. So, where is the problem, what doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the anchor tag `<a>` for links in HTML.
Since you want an image to act like a link, enclose the `<img>` tag in the `<a>` tag like so.

```
<div class="social-media">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
      .....
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer may be correct, but it will be clearer if you add it to the explanation about it.